# Spark ML broadcast model once

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Background: I have a spark-ml trained random forest model. I am reading data from Kafka (streaming) which will pass through the model and the predictions will be saved in database.

What I want:  I want to load my model once and broadcast that model only once when my applications will start and only redeploy if I want to.

My understanding: The model gets loaded and broadcasted for each micro-batches.

Question: How do I make my model load only once and not again for each micro batches so that it persists till the end.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Broadcast will happen only once unless you iterate it in a loop.  If you want to rebuild model with streaming data then broadcasting every time makes sense.

Comment: so the point is, I will write my broadcast in the main function. Is the main for spark called again for every micro batch?.